# angular 9+ ssr redirect with http status code 301?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

`Angular 9+` ssr app

I want to redirect from route guard with `http` status code 301, based on some condition.

I have found a lots of articles and even answered questions here, but non of them works for `angular9+`, they only do their job for the previous angular versions, so

Is there any solution for this or only way to solve this issue is to downgrade `Angular 9+` app to `Angular 8`